# How to reset the value of all buttons with one button

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I can't figure out how to reset the value of all buttons back to 0 as default by just one reset button, can anyone help please?

JS

```
var button1 = 0;
var button1 = 0;

function onClick1() {
  button1 += 1;
  document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = button1;
  };

 function onClick2() {
  button2 += 1;
  document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML = button2;
 };
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" onClick="onClick1()">Click</button>
<p><a id="button1">0</a></p>
<button type="button" onClick="onClick2()">Click</button>
<p><a id="button2">0</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

JS:

```
function onClickReset() {
  button1
  document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = button1;
  button2
  document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML = button2;
  // .. other code to set buttons to default state
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onClick="onClickReset()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Correct, you will need to add additional css into the `onClickReset()` function to reset all the `visual` states (i.e. colors, visbility) back to default. You may also need to reset other `functional` states if the default state has more complicated logics.

Comment: @charlie97 I fixed it by adding the corresponding code here: https://jsbin.com/rosefosumi/edit?html,output
The changes are:
   `button1 = 0;`
   `document.getElementById("button1").value = button1;`
   `...`
to the ResetButton()
Please check if I missed anything.

Comment: @charlie97 Great! It'd be great if you can upvote and accurately indicate the correct answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to address more than just the resetting of the numbers.

Consider dropping `onclick` handlers in favour of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It's best practices, as the `on*` event attributes and DOM properties are quite outdated. [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) keeps it all in JavaScript, and helps to promote separation of concerns.

Another thing is to consider which elements you are utilizing in your markup. Anchors and paragraphs are likely not what you want, as they don't make sense semantically. I would drop the paragraph, and use a `readonly` input element (since it is changing on user input, afterall). Wrap it all up in a `form` and you can use the standard [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) behaviour.

Use CSS to get desired spacing, and visual effects.

Consider the following:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function increment (event) {
  var input = this.nextElementSibling,
      value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;

  input.value = value;
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', increment);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <button type="button">Click</button>
    <input type="text" value="0" readonly />
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="button">Click</button>
    <input type="text" value="0" readonly />
  </div>

  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This should work in all modern browsers (IE9+). Make sure your markup is in the proper order, and it is wrapped in a `form`, like I've shown. For simplicity I have relied on the structure of the markup for `nextElementSibling` to work in this example, so make sure your read only `input` elements directly follow their `button` partner. Without that order, you'll need to get a little more wordy with your element search, or use `data` attributes to find the target input directly.

Comment: Make sure your script tag comes after your DOM elements. Place it just before the closing `</body>` tag. If you place it in the `<head>`, the `button` elements will not exist when `document.querySelector` is invoked. [Here is an example](https://jsbin.com/mijenaceyo/edit?html,output).

Comment: The code I've shown stores the count directly on the input element, as the current value, not as a global variable. The reset button simply resets the form's elements to their default values. I would suggest you start reading (not skimming) through some [web tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials), and properly learn HTML, then JavaScript and the DOM. You're making _a lot_ of mistakes - too many to address in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty easy...just add another button, and have it's onclick function be:

```
function onClick3(){
    button1=button2=-1;
    onClick1();onClick2();
}
```

Comment: no, there are lots of ways to do it. Is there any specific way you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there is a third button to `Reset` so HTML will be:

```
<button type="button" onClick="onClick3()">Reset</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function onClick3() {
   button1 = 0
   button2 = 0
   document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = button1;
   document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML = button2;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button onclick="reset()">Reset<button>
```

Javascript

```
function reset() {
  button1=0;
  button2=0;
  onClick1();
  onClick2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.forEach()` to set `button1` , `button2` variables to `0` , each `a` element with `id` beginning with `"button"` to `0`

```js
var button1 = 0;
var button2 = 0;

function onClick1() {
  button1 += 1;
  document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = button1;
};

function onClick2() {
  button2 += 1;
  document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML = button2;
};

function reset() {
  button1 = button2 = 0;
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id^=button]"), function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = button1
  });
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="onClick1()">Click</button>
<p><a id="button1">0</a>
</p>
<button type="button" onClick="onClick2()">Click</button>
<p><a id="button2">0</a>
</p>
<input type="reset" onclick="reset()"/>
```

Comment: @charlie97 Yes. `js` at solution should return values back to `0` , or "default" . _"colour"_ not appear at original Question . `button` `html` , or `css` could be set to any value at `reset` function , called when `input type="reset"` element clicked